# PhpStorm generate template from code selection

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I frequently use PhpStorm's Extract variable & method refactorings. Is there a way to add/extend functionality that could create a new template file from the selected code, prompt for desired template path, and create an include/require statement for that template?

I'm asking either for an entry point into coding this functionality, or extending existing functionality. Or maybe it's already available and I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ástþór mentioned, there is no such way to change the refactoring templates.

You can use [surround with live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) to emulate this behavior. This will not find duplicates and will not replace them as well, but may be it's close enough what you want.

1. Add a surround live template like this one. Open the editor with `Ctrl+Alt+S`:

[image: add live template]

2. Edit the variables in order to get a nicer UX:

[image: edit template variables]

3. Select the variable you want to extract and select `Code > Surround with Live Templates` from the menu or press `Ctrl+Alt+J`.
4. Adjust the templates to your needs.

   - [Live template variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html)

HTH

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. You can ask this question at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development
Other useful sources: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html & https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Setting-up+environment+for+PhpStorm+plugin+development